# Is possible to call closeMenu method of ons-sliding-menu component from back button event?

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui

I want to close `ons-sliding-menu` when the user presses android's back button. How can I achieve this? Current implementation is:

```js
    var manager = {
        initialize: function() {
            this.bindEvents();
        },
        bindEvents: function() {
            document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
        },
        onDeviceReady: function(){
            document.addEventListener("backbutton", manager.onBackKeyDown, false);
            document.addEventListener("menubutton", manager.onMenuKeyDown, false);
        },
        onBackKeyDown: function(){
            // close ons-sliding-menu if opened
        },
        onMenuKeyDown: function(){
            // close or open ons-sliding-menu
        }
    };
    
    manager.initialize();
```

I've tried to call `ons.slidingMenu.toggleMenu()`, however `ons` is `undefined` when `onBackKeyDown` event triggers.

Comment: I'd probably do it by attaching an event listener to $routeChangeStart event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the OnsenuUi 1.1.x has the component ons-back-button

Answer (score 0):

This can probably be achieve through the use of an event listener on `$routeChangeStart` event.  Something like this should do it.

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function () {
  // I'd probably rename this function no to something like closeMenuIfOpen??
  manager.onBackKeyDown();
});
```

Comment: @JonathanPrates sorry I don't know onsen ui - however you are writing angular so it agnostic to ui (to an extent in the controller at least)